# Is a Java class with a generic parameter still a POJO?

Tags: java

Example:

```
class MyClass<S> {
}
```

Is the above class a POJO?

EDIT: The question has been put on hold so let me explain further. Firstly, the question is very clear and precise. Secondly, I think it is important since numerous docs says things like (to quote the google docs at https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities):

> In the Endpoint methods, the return value type cannot be simple type such as String or int. The return value needs to be a POJO, an array or a Collection.

In such a case I would want to know exactly what classes I can use without having to go through a tedious trial-and-error process.

Comment: Let's say it is. POJO isn't an official term, anyway.

Comment: Any java class is a POJO. Provided POJO officially meanins Plain Old Java Object.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Well, that's pushing it into tautology. POJO does mean *something*.

Comment: @Floris I added another answer to explain *why* your class is a POJO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Java Class which doesnt extend prespecified classes and doesnt implement prespecified Interfaces. Also a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) doesnt have a prespecified Annotation.

This means your example is a POJO.

Comment: Please edit your answer to confirm my example is a POJO and I'll accept.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that your example is a POJO.. I edited and confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

The term POJO (plain old java object) became popular around the time of early version of J2EE (now called JEE) and Enterprise Java Beans (EJB).

EJB sought to extend the java-beans philosophy of reusable, component driven architectures by providing enterprise service abstractions - things like database access, security, messaging.

Unfortunately, these early attempts required extending base classes that could only be used within the context of an application server. This had a lot of problems, for example it made testing a very cumbersome and slow process.

As a counterpoint to this POJOs emerged which aimed to provide enterprise services without having to extend base classes. Spring used Dependency Injection and Aspect Oriented Programming for this, and quickly became popular as classes could now easily be unit and integration tested outside of the heavy app server.

The idea behind POJO is that your class should extend from the business domain rather than an infrastructure domain. Therefore yes, there's no reason why a POJO can't use generics, as long as it honors this philosophy.